# Why does this CSS3 transition only work on one side?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
}
.wrapper > div {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper > div img {
display: block;
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
margin: 5% auto 0px auto;
}
.wrapper > div:hover {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 2;
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: .5s;
transition-timing-function: ease;
}
.left {
background: #000000;
left: 0;
}
.right {
background: #ffffff;
right: 0;
```

When you hover the mouse over the left side it does what it's supposed to but when you hover on the right side it goes crazy and doesn't work, any idea why?

Edit: I had linked the wrong JSFiddle, here is the correct one:
http://jsfiddle.net/TjJrs/

Comment: it works... hover the blue expand to the right.. and hover the red expand to the left.. thats right?

Comment: Probably because you have specified the `left` property to 0. Try `left: 100%` first instead of `right` and see if that works

Comment: where is the fiddle gone?

Comment: Solved! JofryHS you pretty much nailed it except it was left: 50%

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left: 0;` in:

```
.wrapper > div:hover {

    width: 100%;
    /*left: 0;*/ 
    z-index: 2;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: .5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TjJrs/2/)